# An if statement for an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, if-statement

How do I make a two dimensional array an if statement.

```
for row in range(6):
    for column in range(7):
        if board[row][column] > 0:
            Draw = True
```

I have a grid of blank squares, 7 by 6, and if a square is clicked its given a value of 1 and if not it stays 0. When all the squares have been clicked making the now 1 I want Draw = True, but this statement above finds the row and column I've just chosen rather then the entire grid.

Comment: Need more clarification. Do you mean when the whole board is "1" then set draw = True?

Comment: yeah thats what I mean, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean check the whole board if all are 1's, then its a simple fix.

```
DRAW = True

for row in range(6):
    for column in range(7):
        if board[row][column] == 0:
            DRAW = False
```

Going about it the other way is easier.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is only when all `board` values are 1, the `Draw` is set to True. You code will set `Draw` to 1 if there is ANY grid clicked.

The solution is simple, you can think reversely, preset the `Draw` to True and whenever the grid is not 1, set it to False.

```
Draw = True
for row in range(6):
    for column in range(7):
        if board[row][column] == 0:
            Draw = False
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check that all values in a collection have a value that is `True` you could always use the built in [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function which checks that all values in an iterable satisfy a given condition (which, in your case is `i > 0`):

```
if all(i > 0 for i in board[row] for row in range(6)):
    Draw = True
```

Which can get simplified to:

```
if all(i for i in board[row] for row in range(6)): 
    Draw = True
```

Since positive values evaluate to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all` as another way to @Wboy's forloop:

```
all(x for y in z for x in y)

#or x !=0 but that's redundant here since 1 equates to True.
```

Here, z would be your two dimensional list. You can evaluate uneven dimensions this way as well without getting "bogged" down in ranges etc.

**Caveat**: If you had an empty list in your grid, then `all` here would still evaluate to true.

Example grid for caveat:

```
[[],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1], #some more rand elements of the grid, first one's the point.
]
```

Comment: Ah yes, much nicer way to do it :)